# Is this considered memoisation?

Tags: optimization, naming, memoization

In optimising some code recently, we ended up performing what I think is a "type" of memoisation but I'm not sure we should be calling it that. The pseudo-code below is not the *actual* algorithm (since we have little need for factorials in our application, and posting said code is a firing offence) but it should be adequate for explaining my question. This was the original:

```
def factorial (n):
    if n == 1 return 1
    return n * factorial (n-1)
```

Simple enough, but we added fixed points so that large numbers of calculations could be avoided for larger numbers, something like:

```
def factorial (n):
    if n == 1 return 1
    if n == 10 return 3628800
    if n == 20 return 2432902008176640000
    if n == 30 return 265252859812191058636308480000000
    if n == 40 return 815915283247897734345611269596115894272000000000
    # And so on.

    return n * factorial (n-1)
```

This, of course, meant that `12!` was calculated as `12 * 11 * 3628800` rather than the less efficient `12 * 11 * 10 * 9 * 8 * 7 * 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1`.

But I'm wondering whether we *should* be calling this memoisation since that seems to be defined as *remembering* past results of calculations and using them. This is more about hard-coding calculations (not remembering) and using that information.

Is there a proper name for this process or can we claim that memoisation extends back not just to calculations done at run-time but also those done at compile-time and even back to those done in my head before I even start writing the code?

Comment: Yes.  It is a kind of memoization.  What more do you need to know?

Comment: _That's_ what I need to know. It doesn't gel with the Wikipedia entry which specifically states: `A memoized function "remembers" the results corresponding to some set of specific inputs. Subsequent calls with remembered inputs return the remembered result rather than recalculating it, ...`. I thought there may be a different term for the case where it doesn't remember but instead has it hardcoded in.

Comment: Okay, I have two answers so far, yes and no. That means references to sources of authority are probably going to be needed. I'll leave the question for a few hours and see what comes in.

Comment: "sources of authority are probably going to be needed"?  Really?  Why does it matter if this is proper memoization, nearly memoization, not really memoization or not memoization at all?  Is there money riding on the result of your poll?

Comment: It matters because we should all want to use the correct *terms* for what we're discussing. It's no different to someone wanting to know if a bubble sort can be called a quick sort, or whether an algorithm is O(1) or O(n).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd call it pre-calculation rather than memoization.  You're not really remembering any of the calculations you've done in the process of calculating a final answer for a given input, rather you're pre-calculating some fixed number of answers for specific inputs.  Memoization as I understand it is really more akin to "caching" a set of results as you calculate them for later reuse.  If you were to store each value calculated so that you didn't need to recalculate it again later, that would be memoization.  Your solution differs in that you never store any "calculated" results from your program, only the fixed points that have been pre-calculated.  With memoization if you reran the function with an input different than one of the pre-calculated ones it would not have to recalculate the result, it would simply reuse it.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not you are hard coding the results in, this is still memoization because you have already calculated results that you are expecting to calculate again. Now this may come in the form of run-time, or compile time.. but either way, it's memoization.

Answer (score 1):

Memoization is done at run-time. You are optimizing at compile time. So, it is not.

See for example ... [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization#Overview)

Or ...

> 1. Memoization 
>      The  term memoization  was  coined  by  Donald  Michie  (1968)  to  refer  to  the  process  by which  a  function  is  made  to  **automatically**  remember  the  results  of  previous  computations.  The  idea  has  become more  popular  in  recent  years  with  the  rise  of  functional languages;  Field  and  Harrison  (1988)  devote  a  whole  chapter  to  it.  The  basic  idea  is just  to  keep  a  table  of  previously  computed  input/result  pairs.

**Peter Norvig**
University  of California 
(the bold is mine)

[Link](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology-new/J/J91/J91-1004.pdf)

Comment: When is this mysterious "run time"?  Can I cache results from previous runs in persistent storage?  If so, can I cache results from previous runs in the executable code itself?  If so, can I cache results from previous runs in the source code?  I don't see why there's a random line excluding "caching previous results in the source code".

Comment: @S.Lott As always, words are just words, and a definition is always objectionable. I think the concept used by the OP diverges from the usual memoization definition because 1) He is forced to modify the function to store new/other results and 2) In the usual sense "a function is made to automatically remember the results of previous computations" without human intervention (hence the _automatically_). Nobody will die if there is no agreement in such a thing.

Comment: @belisarius: So, the way to pass the memoization test would be to have the function rewrite it's own source code?

Comment: @S.Lott You may make the function to write a LISP interpreter to modify itself. More seriously, I think everything from reading a configuration file only once, to storing previously calculated  interest amounts in a DB could be called memoization if you wish to. None of those is the usual word usage.

Comment: @belisarius: "None of those is the usual word usage".  Agreed.  But why not?  What is the random line that's being drawn?  You highlighted "automatically", but that seems to mean almost anything.  Since the question is fussy and legalistic, I'm trying to understand the fussy legalistic hair that you're splitting.

Comment: “When I use a word," Humpty Dumpty said in rather a scornful tone, "it means just what I choose it to mean - neither more nor less.” And so it is with memoization.

Comment: @Neal That is valid also for memosnarks

Answer (score 0):

```
def memoisation(f):
    dct = {}
    def myfunction(x):
        if x not in dct:            
            dct[x] = f(x)
        return dct[x]
    return myfunction

@memoisation
def fibonacci(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)

def nb_appels(n):
    if n==0 or n==1:
        return 0
    else:
        return  1 + nb_appels(n-1) + 1 + nb_appels(n-2)


print(fibonacci(13))
print ('nbappel',nb_appels(13))
```